# System.ArgumentException when trying to pass Action as arguement to COM method via VSTO

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop

I try to pass an action to a VSTO class in order to get the content of a mailitem.

But, when I call Register method, i get System.ArgumentException.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IOutlookUtilities
{
    void Register(Action<Outlook.MailItem> action);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class AddInUtilities : StandardOleMarshalObject, IOutlookUtilities
{
    [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
    public Action<Outlook.MailItem> ExtractMail;

    public static AddInUtilities instance;

    public AddInUtilities()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void Register(Action<Outlook.MailItem> action)
    {
        this.ExtractMail = action;
    }
}
```

In another c# solution:

```
private void Form1()
{
        Outlook.Application outlook = (Outlook.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Outlook.Application");

        Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIns addins = outlook.COMAddIns;

        if(addins != null)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn addin = addins.Item("OutlookAddin1");

            if(addin != null)
            {
                Action<Outlook.MailItem> action = new Action<Outlook.MailItem>((mail) =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(mail.Subject);
                });

                addin.Object.Register(action); //<--exception from this line
            }
        }
}
```

The exception message : System.ArgumentException: 'Type'System.__ComObject' object is unable cast to 'System.Action`1[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem]'。'

I've try to pass other types of class.
It seems when I try to pass a class type into a method of addin.Object. It always says unable to cast  into .

Comment: as you can see from exception message: `ComObject` are not playing well with `Action<MailItem>`

Comment: any way i can fix it?

Comment: or I may be wrong, and your code somewhere is trying to cast `System.__ComObject` to `System.Action`1[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem]`

Comment: Exception is from the line "addin.Object.Register(action)"